# Default values in SQLite3

Tags: database-design, sqlite, alter-table, ddl

When I created the table structure of my SQLite database, I provided a `DEFAULT` value which is used when no value is provided by the user. Now, because the application code changed, I need to modify the default but can't seem to find how to do it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite only implements a [very limited subset of `ALTER TABLE` statements](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html). You'll have to drop and recreate the table, preferably in one transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_tmp(col1, col2);
INSERT INTO tbl_tmp SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl;
DROP TABLE tbl;
CREATE TABLE tbl(col1 integer, col2 text DEFAULT 'foo'); -- with new default
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl_tmp;
DROP TABLE tbl_tmp;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, Erwin. Answers my question and solves my problem. Much appreciated.